# Newbie problem with react-native project initialization

Tags: ruby, react-native

When I run `npx react-native projectname`, the project is only created partially.

Now when I run `bundle install` I get:

`1. Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.`

`2. An error occurred while installing ffi (1.15.5), and Bundler cannot continue. Make sure that "gem install ffi -v '1.15.5' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'" succeeds before bundling.`

[image]

Yes, I have installed the ffi 1.15.5 (below screenshot) but it is still saying I dont have it

[image]

**Ruby version**: ruby 2.7.5p203 (2021-11-24 revision f69aeb8314) [arm64-darwin21]

**pod** --version: 1.11.3

I am impressed how difficult it is to start a project. Someone please help

Comment: Post the output of `gem install ffi -v '1.15.5' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` please.

Also, try installing `sudo apt install libffi-dev` first

Comment: @Sumak Hi Sumak, refer to my 2nd screenshot for that. It says it installs just fine. But later on it will say that it is missing even though it is clearly installed

Comment: What about sudo apt install libffi-dev ?